# R 3.2.2 - Windows 8.1 - Can't run R-3.2.2-win.exe (installer)

Tags: r, installation, windows-8.1

when I try to run the executable for an R 3.2.2 installer downloaded from a cran mirror, I get an error which says:

"Unable to execute file in the temporary directory. Setup aborted.
Error 5: Access is denied."

I've tried several solutions found here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/unable-to-execute-files-in-the-temporary-directory/0d441663-6167-420d-b936-53f9c3d17898?auth=1

None have prevented the error. Please assist me!

Comment: Have you tried to run as adminstrator ? Disabled antivirus ? Have you run procmon and filtered for fails ? This should tell you which file causes the error 5.

Comment: @Marged I have tried running as admin and have disabled antivirus. What is procmon?

Comment: Procmon is a tool that (besides other things) monitors file access of processes. You will seesee which files get written by the installer and where it fails.

Answer (score 1):

After following these solutions to no avail, I decided to turn my firewall BACK ON and play some league of legends. I clicked the R-3.2.2-win.exe just for giggles and what do you know, the installer RAN PERFECTLY...